# converting ascii to unicode example BB 10 and vise versa

Tags: qml, blackberry-10, blackberry-cascades

can anyone help me in converting a QString into  unicode from Ascii and vice versa

If possible add some code snippet.

Thanks,

Comment: I am trying ...QByteArray qbyte(key.toUtf8(), key.size());QTextCodec coder=QTextCodec::toUnicode(qbyte); where key is QString, but i am gettings error like with in the scope

Answer (score 0, accepted):

QString provides the toUtf8() function that returns a const char * version of the string as QByteArray. QString also provides fromUtf8().

B.T.W. The Qt technical pages provide plenty of examples.